# Thermodynamics and wall insulation

Tags: thermodynamics

Australia's history has been littered with the problem of how to manage safety in bushfires. The local fire authority recommend consideration be given to preparing a bushfire management plan, deciding whether to stay and defend, or leave early.

A back- up plan is also suggested, which may include the use of a personal fire bunker.

Temperatures can be up to $935^\circ C$ in a bushfire, and above ground bunkers are marketed as being safe for one hour.

Fire loads can peak at $100kWm^{-2}$.

My question relates to the effectiveness of fire bunkers to provide safe shelter in a fire. Key aspects of this are the ability of the bunker to achieve the following criteria: 1. Non combustible construction 2. Limit heat flow through walls to $2.5kWm^{-2}$ 3. Limit max surface temperature on the inside walls to $75^\circ C$ 4. Limit air temperature on the inside walls to $40^\circ C$; 5. Fire rated door, with non-combustible seal;

Research into this topic has yielded the following: 1. English fire expert experienced in fire door testing and fire gasket seals says it can't be done; expect the people in the bunker to be microwaved; 2. USA makes tornado/hurricane safe refuges, nominally fire resistant, but Californian authority advice is: not to be used in a wildfire.

My question relates to the meeting of the nominated Aus standards. Some finite element studies I have done into items 1,2,3 says all three can be achieved.

Items 4 and 5 are problematic.

Item 4 is the internal air temp. Even with a heat flow reduction from $100kWm^{-2}$ to $2.5kWm^{-2}$, as nominated in the Aus guidelines, if there is a fire refuge in lockdown, with limited air mass, no ventilation, prelim studies into this show the temp will rise. Lots.

This is based on: $Q=mC_{p}\Delta T$

It is a one liner, but says the temp goes up. A lot. Not a lot of mass in the air. Lots of exposed area in the walls and roof.

With better insulation, we can get this heat input down to $0.5kWm^{-2}$. This is lower than sunlight.

But the Time to heat up above $40^\circ C$ from a base of $35^\circ C$ is still very low, based on this formula, much lower than 60 mins target.

As a structural engineer with many years in structures, who is doing this as a bit of a hobby, I am heading back to my Uni notes to help. No doubt I am missing something; or are the Brits/US authorities on the right track?

To complicate the issue, there are people in the bunker, all huffing and puffing as the temp rises. That complicates the physics a bit more.

Item 5 Heat seal; smoke seal; air seal. Again a bit problematic as fire doors distort and let air in. Break the seal. Also internal temperature rise also heats up the internal air pressure. Which would also break the seal.

---

Trust this gives a bit of background into what is an interesting problem. Would appreciate people's feedback on possible ways to better evaluate the internal room temperature/pressure rise in the bunker.

Comment: Reposting is not an acceptable response to having a question closed.

Comment: @dmckee Just a passer-by, but why on earth is a question as good as this closed? A "duplicate"? Of what, exactly? I thought this was supposed to be a forum which nurtured original thought and provided practical and theoretical answers? Disgusting. I happen to also live in rural Australia and would love to see suggestions to this issue.

Comment: @wild_nothing This question was closed exactly and entirely because the OP reposted after the original was closed, contrary to the rules of this place. The original was subsequently auto-deleted for having negative total score and no upvoted answers. The place to argue the utility of the questions was either in the comments of the original or on meta.

Comment: @dmckee I fail to see why a question like this was closed to begin with?  Maybe you can shed some light on that? Or at least do the community a favour and reopen it or delete it so that I myself can re-submit it.

Comment: @wild_nothing actually this _isn't_ a good question for this site. The biggest issue is that it's not asking anything specific, and in particular not asking about a specific physics concept. I'm sure this is a good question somewhere online, but not here. If you'd like to ask a question on this topic yourself, you can do that, but make sure to (1) make it specific, (2) make it about a physics concept, not  about engineering or design requirements, (3) make it clear what you're actually asking, and (4) make sure you're not just asking us to calculate something for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a reasonable technical solution to your problem, but I suspect that, from the point of view of physics, item 4 is manageable in principle: the inside of the bunker does not have to be empty. For example, you can keep a couple of tons of water in the bunker:-) You can also consider boiling latent heat for some liquid, but this can add some problems with pressure.